# Cumulative frequency from largest to smallest

Tags: r

I have four variables (M,N,O,P) and I want to plot them using val as
Cumulative frequency (from largest to smallest) in y axis and the
Loc (location) in x-axis. Can you please help me in graphing the cumulative
frequency from largest to smallest value using R?

```
    head(data)
      Loc variable val
    1  1  M      35.5
    2  2  M      10.0
    3  3  M      68.5
    4  4  M      74.0
    5  5  M      7.5
    6  6  M       49.0
........................
........................
      32 P     0.8913642
      33 P     14.7647320
      34 P    92.4376504
      35 P     2.2597151
      36 P    39.3573232
      37 P     32.5501549
```

I just wanted a graph like this, where the color graphs are cumulative value of the four variables (M,N,O,P) from largest to smallest:
[image]

Comment: @IceCreamToucan, I want from "largest to smallest" and Loc to the x-axis and the location increases as we go down.

Comment: It doesn't properly give me the plot based on the four variables I mentioned in the question.

Comment: I'm confused about how the 4 variables fit in.  Are they all on the same plot?  Can you find some sample data to illustrate with? Maybe simplify it down to two variables.  Is Loc unique for each row?

Comment: Thanks@Elin and I added the tail of the data. Each variable is available in each location and there are about 37 locations. what is the key thing to graph cumulative frequency to plot from largest to smallest value?

Comment: Rather than (or in addition to) posting `head(data)` and `tail(data)`, it would help if you posted the results of `dput(head(data))`, etc. Also, rather than doing that exactly, mock up a small example in which all 4 variables appear. Your question as written isn't very clear.

Answer (score 2):

The best way of doing this is to use packages `dplyr`, to prepare the data, and `ggplot` to do the plotting.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  arrange(variable, val) %>%
  mutate(x = row_number()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, val, colour = variable)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

For a cumulative plot of `val`, include an instruction

```
val = cumsum(val)
```

in the `mutate`, right after `x = row_number()`.

```
data %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  arrange(variable, val) %>%
  mutate(x = row_number(),
         val = cumsum(val)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, val, colour = variable)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]
**Data.**

```
data <- read.table(text = "
Loc variable val
1  M      35.5
2  M      10.0
3  M      68.5
4  M      74.0
5  M      7.5
6  M       49.0
32 P     0.8913642
33 P     14.7647320
34 P    92.4376504
35 P     2.2597151
36 P    39.3573232
37 P     32.5501549
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks@Rui Barrada, the graph is exactly what I want in the cumulative frequencey but the graph is just normal, it seems that you havenot used cumulative frequency from largest to smallest value. Please use in that way, like ecdf or other function to get the cumulative frequency.

Comment: @Stackuser Done see the edit with the new code and graph.

Comment: in addition, I got this error: Error in group_by(., variable) : could not find function "group_by"

Comment: @Stackuser In my call to `library(ggplot2)` I had a typo, it was written `ggplot` without the `2`. Function `group_by` needs `library(dplyr)`, which is correctly called in the very beginning of the script.

Comment: Thank you very much @Rui Barradas for your help but for large set of data, it doesn't give me the proper graph. Does it have the normal plot version (plot) of this ggplot code? If it has , I appreciate otherwise thanks again for your effort.